# How to remove pop out icon in google docs viewer?

Tags: android

I am using google docs viewer in android to display pdf. I want to remove the pop out option. Refer the attached screenshot.[Screenshot of google docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoU0a.png)

Here is the code I am using to load in webview.

```
webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.text_studyguide);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url="+pdfURL);
webview.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String failingUrl) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }
        })
```

Comment: @dilipchandar Welcome 

Comment: @Mohammad: Welcome :)

Comment: it hide icon only, how to remove or change transparent color to button? plz help me

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Solution:

```
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b')[0].style.visibility='hidden'; })()")
        }

    }
```